# how to create a backup file using java servlet

Tags: java

I am using this code to backup my database but the resulting backup file is empty. Once I copy the command and paste it on the terminal without the Password it generates a similar file but once I key in the password the backup is created successfully. I wish to know whether my code is passing the password to the terminal or whether its the reason why it's not populating the backup file.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Backup extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat fa = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        String f = fa.format(today);
        SimpleDateFormat fb = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        String g = fb.format(today);
        SimpleDateFormat fc = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        String h = fc.format(today);
        SimpleDateFormat fd = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
        String d = fd.format(today);
        SimpleDateFormat fe = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        String l = fe.format(today);
        SimpleDateFormat fi = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
        String i = fi.format(today);

       try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "dbUser", 
    "P@ssw0rd");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT @@basedir");

            while (rs.next()) {
            String  a = rs.getString(1);
                out.println("<h2>"+a+" </h2>");

                String pass = new String("P@ssw0rd");

           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] 
    {"cmd.exe","/c","cd "+a+"\"bin\" && mysqldump -h localhost  -P 3306 -B 
    dbname -u  dbUser -p "+pass+" --add-drop-database -r 
    C:\\TLLBackups\\backup-"+h+"-"+f+"-"+g+"-"+d+"-"+l+"-"+i+".sql" });
            int processComplete = p.waitFor();
            if (processComplete == 0) {
                out.println(" Backup successful");
            }else {
                BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                String line;
                out.println(" Backup failed, ");
            while((line=err.readLine())!= null){
                out.println("Error: "+line);
            }
        }

         }


    }catch(SQLException ex){
        out.println("<h2> Database not reachable.</h2>");

                Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
    null, ex);
    }catch(Exception e){
            Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
    e);


    }

    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sending the string  "+pass+" , you most likely meant  + pass + without the double-quotes

Comment: +pass+ is a string variable  between  a cmd command. If I remove the double  quotes  then the cmd command will have pass as the password  instead of a variable I hope to pass from  the session.